# PHP-login form not working

Tags: php

I was making a Login form, but it did not do anything once submit the form.. The PHP does not work.. 
Nothing works. This is my code:

Login.php:

```
<?
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "DB");
    //Login Script
    if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
        $user_login = ($_POST["email"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
        $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
        $md5password_login = md5($password_login);
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' AND closed='no' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
        //Check for their existance
        $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
        if ($userCount == 1) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
                 $id = $row["id"];
        }
             $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
             $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
             $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
             exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
            } else {
            echo 'That information is incorrect, try again';
            exit();
        }
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login to Music and Science!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("login-button").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $('form').fadeOut(500);
            $('.wrapper').addClass('form-success');
        });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300);
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        body {
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            /* WebKit browsers */
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        body :-moz-placeholder {
            /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            opacity: 1;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        body ::-moz-placeholder {
            /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            opacity: 1;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        body :-ms-input-placeholder {
            /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        .wrapper {
            background: #50a3a2;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin-top: -310px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .wrapper.form-success .container h1 {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(85px);
            -ms-transform: translateY(85px);
            transform: translateY(85px);
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 80px 0;
            height: 400px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .container h1 {
            font-size: 40px;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-duration: 1s;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
            font-weight: 200;
        }
        form {
            padding: 20px 0;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        form input {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            outline: 0;
            border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            width: 250px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: white;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
            transition-duration: 0.25s;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        form input:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
        }
        form input:focus {
            background-color: white;
            width: 300px;
            color: #53e3a6;
        }
        form button {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            outline: 0;
            background-color: white;
            border: 0;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            color: #53e3a6;
            border-radius: 3px;
            width: 250px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 18px;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
            transition-duration: 0.25s;
        }
        form button:hover {
            background-color: #f5f7f9;
        }
        .bg-bubbles {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .bg-bubbles li {
            position: absolute;
            list-style: none;
            display: block;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
            bottom: -160px;
            -webkit-animation: square 25s infinite;
            animation: square 25s infinite;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
            transition-timing-function: linear;
        }
        .bg-bubbles li:nth-child(1) {
            left: 10%;
        }
        .bg-bubbles li:nth-child(2) {
            left: 20%;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
            animation-delay: 2s;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 17s;
            animation-duration: 17s;
        }
        .bg-bubbles li:nth-child(3) {
            left: 25%;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
            animation-delay: 4s;
        }
        .bg-bubbles li:nth-child(4) {
            left: 40%;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 22s;
            animation-duration: 22s;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
        }
        .bg-bubbles li:nth-child(5) {
            left: 70%;
        }
        .bg-bubbles li:nth-child(6) {
            left: 80%;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
            animation-delay: 3s;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        }
        .bg-bubbles li:nth-child(7) {
            left: 32%;
            width: 160px;
            height: 160px;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 7s;
            animation-delay: 7s;
        }
        .bg-bubbles li:nth-child(8) {
            left: 55%;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
            animation-delay: 15s;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
            animation-duration: 40s;
        }
        .bg-bubbles li:nth-child(9) {
            left: 25%;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
            animation-delay: 2s;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
            animation-duration: 40s;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        }
        .bg-bubbles li:nth-child(10) {
            left: 90%;
            width: 160px;
            height: 160px;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 11s;
            animation-delay: 11s;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes square {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
                transform: translateY(0);
            }
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
                transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            }
        }
        @keyframes square {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
                transform: translateY(0);
            }
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
                transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            }
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

                <form class="form" method="POST" action="#">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    <input type="password" name="password_login" placeholder="Password">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <ul class="bg-bubbles">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>     
    </html>
```

No errors are displayed and I don't know whats wrong.
Please help..

Thanks!

Comment: Remove # from action="#"

Comment: change button to input type submit and so many other error's in code check it carefully like in j-query u have not given '#' while taking button's id

Comment: still not working....

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean on line 10

Comment: Id fix this <? - to <?php, maybe that works with short tags enabled but I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing libaries. `mysqli` **DOES NOT** = `mysql`. What you want is this:

```
$userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

The same thing goes for `$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)`, that'll need to be:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)
```

Also, your sessions won't be set, because you haven't started it! If you want to use sessions, you need to start them on **every** page that you intend to use them on:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Please don't ever use this code in production. It's vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should sanitize the variables at minimum, but use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [Mysqli Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) instead.

---

**Note:** It seems you have PHP short tags on (`<? ?>`) so that isn't the issue, but not every host will have them turned on, so it's best to use the proper tags:

```
<?php

...... your code

?>
```